# Adding IBM Watson Package to Java code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ibm-watson

I am working on creating Java code to analyze text using [IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/natural-language-understanding/). I am using Eclipse Luna on a MacBook Pro.

I have built the Maven Project, created an account with IBM (access key, etc.) and am using [GitHub](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/natural-language-understanding/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/natural_language_understanding) to get the code.

The problem I am having is the package. This is the line:
package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.v1;

I was hoping that setting up Maven would provide a link to the package but it does not. I've been trying to find where and how to download the package into Eclipse with no luck.

Any advice on how to get and install the package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hi I think you need to have a deeper look at the Githup page that you mentioned in the Question.

If Maven is failing to import the library I'm assuming that you need to add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if it works for you, I can provide additional help if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I gave that a try and then selected Maven build - generate sources.  I noted that I was still getting the error in the code. When I selected it, it gave me the option of moving the package into the java code.  I selected that and it seemed to work.  I'll experiment so more and let you know if this solved the problem.